# How to create a table in mysql with long name?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table with long name.
For now I can create only 63 long titled table.

Comment: **Theoretically** (without knowing why you'd want this *at all*) you **MIGHT** be able to change the data type of `information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_NAME` to `varchar(128)`. This **might** break a lot of stuff though, so please consider this a lot before you start changing the MySQL tables.

Comment: I have some complaints about Mysql but the biggest is the character length on tables.Damn only 64, what will I name my next table?

Comment: 64C4 Taking 4 at a time it too long

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

```
Identifier                | Maximum Length (characters)
--------------------------+-------------------------------------
Database                  |  64
Tabl                      |  64
Column                    |  64
Index                     |  64
Constraint                |  64
Stored Procedure or Func  |  64
Trigger                   |  64
View                      |  64
Alias                     | 256 (see exception following table)
Compound Statement Label  |  16
```

Comment: Lol Thanks @h2ooooooooo Looks much nicer xDD

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length for each type of identifier described in MySQL documentation:

```
Identifier  Maximum Length (characters)

Table                    64
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html